# DB PostgreSQL data invisible in my website

Tags: python, django, postgresql

we developing a website and I have a problem with data stored in DB PostgreSQL locally
when I share the code with my team they can't see the data I uploaded to website

how can I fix that or should we use DB and website hosting like Railway
( we use the same usename;and pass of DB server and when i update the database and they pull the code it just update the schema without the data i stored -we use vs
code ide,python lang and Django framework,PostgreSQL DB Github for sharing)

Comment: how they cannot see the images with the same username? do you share a link to the photo with them or do they try to access it with the same db username?

Comment: When they pull the update of code and db ,it’s just the schema updated without the data and images I stored